# Different output from exec if using a mobile browser

Tags: php, exec

This one has me stumped. I have two Windows installations of PHP: 32-bit on a 32-bit OS, and 64-bit on a 64-bit OS. Both use Apache 2.2 (native architectures), and both load php as a module.

Then I have a console application (.Net), which outputs one line with stuff in it. Typically, it will output one word, like E_INVALID_CREDENTIALS, or S_SUCCESS, (custom codes), followed by a colon and random data.

I am using `$e = exec("command")` in PHP and parsing the output of `$e`. However, and I have tested this with a `die($e)` after the `exec` statement, if I use a mobile browser (iPod touch, or Android 2.2), the output of exec is just the first word and a colon, but if I use a desktop browser (Chrome, or Firefox), the output is the complete line as printed by the console application.

I have run the command manually, even printed the command PHP is executing, and I see no reason for truncated output.

Can anyone help me root out this problem?

Comment: I think it might have more to do with the page formatting than with the php code.

Comment: Nope. I did a die($e), pure plaintext output. Still no difference. Also, I am NOT serving differently formatted stuff to desktop browsers. Same page, same styles, same everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. After a few days of debugging, I realized that the username I was sending to the console application was capitalized for mobile browsers. And while a capitalized username did not throw an error, it failed in other, mysterious ways.I should have caught this earlier.  Either way, this was an esoteric bug in the Console Application, and had nothing to do with PHP. I still blame the phones for capitalizing my username...

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side, thus it does not have any connection, if you're not checking user's agent and other client-side information.

If you're really getting different information, be sure your browsers both use same settings (cookies enabled, for example)

But it all depends on your dependencies from code-side and from code as a whole.

Maybe there is everything visible, but you have just wrong CSS or something so it appears differently on different browsers (?)

Comment: I though of that. I have enabled all cookies and stuff. I checked the value and presence of cookies, and they appear exactly the same. In fact, exec even runs the same command, as tested by echoing the contents of the command string. And I do not serve anything different to desktop browsers.